# What is the default InstanceContextMode for a WCF service (using BasicHttpBinding) under Mono?

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, basichttpbinding, instancecontextmode

After bringing my code to Mono 3.2.8, I had a surprise to see that the behavior of my service was always created like using `InstanceContextMode.Single`. Same on Mono 3.12.1. To be more clear, my service is not marked with any `InstanceContextMode` attribute and uses `BasicHttpBinding`.

I know from Microsoft world that default value of `InstanceContextMode` should be **`PerSession`** , but of course when `BasicHttpBinding` is used, then the value will be **`PerCall`**. [This article](http://www.remondo.net/wcf-servicebehavior-instancecontextmode-explained/) explains well, but again, in Microsoft world.

For Mono, I tried googling, but to no avail. [This link](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/wcfstatusold/#instance-behavior) is the only thing I could find, it says only `InstanceContextMode.Single` is implemented, but this documentation is outdated, couldn't find any update on the matter.

And I noticed for Mono 3.12.1, after I explicitly set the `InstanceContextMode.PerCall` that I could get finally the wanted behavior.

Can anyone explain the defaults values of `InstanceContextMode` and explain real behavior in Mono? Would be nice to get some clarity because I will have to maintain the code for both windows and Linux.